# Call log deletion on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android

I wanted to try and programmatically delete the call logs within my phone but from all of the methods I've tried(looked through Google and various questions on here), I am unable to get them to delete. Even apps that are already on the market which I have been using to backup my information so I can test my code doesn't work.

Trying the following does nothing, as well as looping through the records:

```
cursor.delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

All the permissions are there. Does anyone perhaps have any other method or an idea of why this doesn't work on the Galaxy S3?

Thanks